# resolving bluebird promise for array of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I want to read the image paths, convert them into binary data, append an index and then do something else after all the files have been converted. I have the following code:

```
    var bufferData = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < imagePaths.length; i++) {
        bufferData.push({
            data: fs.readFileAsync(imagePaths[i]),
            index: i
            }
        );
    }


    Promise.all(bufferData).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        //do something
    });
```

which returns

```
[ { data: 
 Promise {
   _bitField: 134217728,
   _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
   _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
   _promise0: undefined,
   _receiver0: undefined },
index: 0 } ]
```

It seems like the promise is not being resolved inside the bufferData object. What do I need to do to resolve the promise?

If i do

```
var bufferData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < imagePaths.length; i++) {
    bufferData.push(fs.readFileAsync(imagePaths[i]));
}


Promise.all(bufferData).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    //do something
});
```

it returns:

```
[ <Buffer ff d8 ff e1 18 b9 45 78 69 66 00 00 49 49 2a 00 08 00 00 00 09 00 0f 01 02 00 06 00 00 00 7a 00 00 00 10 01 02 00 0e 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 12 01 03 00 ... > ]
```

which is what I want, but I was not able to append the index.

Answer (score 1):

You're `Promise.all` is being given an array of objects that contain promises, not the promises themselves. You just need to make sure the array is an array of actual promises:

```
for (var i = 0; i < imagePaths.length; i++) {
    var fileIndexPromise = Promise.all([
        fs.readFileAsync(imagePaths[i]),
        i
    ])
    bufferData.push(fileIndexPromise.then(([result, index]) => ({
        data: result,
        index: index
    })));
}


Promise.all(bufferData).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    //do something
});
```

EDIT: It occurs to me that my original post would have given the incorrect value for the index. To fix that, you'll have to include the current index as part of the promise (eg, don't access it via the closure), as otherwise they would all be equal to `imagePaths.length`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the correction. Your solution makes sense and works. I also want to note that you missed a ) in the bufferData.push line.

Comment: not sure why you'd need to have the index like that ... `data[n]` would be the result of `imagePath[n]` promise - so the index seems redundant

Comment: I wanted to index the images because my thought is that the files are read asynchronously (so the 2nd image may be read before the 1st image) and I want to order them the way they came in from the image path.

Comment: @JaromandaX Thats a good point. It was included as I was trying to keep OP's general code structure. @user3559233, the promises in a `Promise.all` maintain the same order in the array, even if they resolve at different times. So you might consider leaving out the index.

Comment: Promise.all preserves the order of the promises, not the order that the promises are resolved in, so, it is redundant

Comment: This one liner, `Promise.all(imagePaths.map(img => fs.readFileAsync(img))).then(results => results.map((data, index) => ({data, index}))).then(results => ` ... the final `results` is an array of `{index, data}` objects, if you really must

Comment: Thanks for the informative suggestions Jaromanda and CRice :) I will look into improving my methods.